# How do I beat Dracul puzzle #3: Rivalry?

Tags: desktop-dungeons

How can I solve the Desktop Dungeons puzzle *Rivalry*, the 3rd puzzle of the "Fresh Blood" puzzle pack?

Answer (score 3):

Just figured this out myself after repeated tries.

1. Take Blood Curse and Blood Hunger.
2. BurnDayRaz, Drink Mana, BurnDayRaz (On the Level 3).
3. Convert BurnDayRaz and Health Potion.
4. Hit x 2 to Kill a Vampire.
5. Desecrate GG's altar.
6. Pick up Pendant of Health.
7. Hit x 4 to Kill 2 Vampires, Level Up.
8. Hit x 2 the Level 3.
9. Kill last Vampire, then Hit Level 3 again.
10. Take Blood Tithe and Blood Swell.
11. Hit the Level 3, Drink 2 Blood Pools.
12. Hit the Level 3, Drink all remaining Blood Pools.
13. Deal the last blow against the Level 3.